# ANN regression, linear function approximation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have built a regular ANN–BP setup with one unit on input and output layer and 4 nodes in hidden with sigmoid. Giving it a simple task to approximate linear `f(n) = n` with n in range 0-100.

**PROBLEM**: Regardless of number of layers, units in hidden layer or whether or not I am using bias in node values it learns to approximate f(n) = Average(dataset) like so:

[image]

Code is written in JavaScript as a proof of concept. I have defined three classes: Net, Layer and Connection, where Layer is an array of input, bias and output values, Connection is a 2D array of weights and delta weights. Here is the Layer code where all important calculations happen:

```
Ann.Layer = function(nId, oNet, oConfig, bUseBias, aInitBiases) {
var _oThis = this;

var _initialize = function() {
        _oThis.id        = nId;
        _oThis.length    = oConfig.nodes;
        _oThis.outputs   = new Array(oConfig.nodes);
        _oThis.inputs    = new Array(oConfig.nodes);
        _oThis.gradients = new Array(oConfig.nodes);
        _oThis.biases    = new Array(oConfig.nodes);

        _oThis.outputs.fill(0);
        _oThis.inputs.fill(0);
        _oThis.biases.fill(0);

        if (bUseBias) {
            for (var n=0; n<oConfig.nodes; n++) {
                _oThis.biases[n] = Ann.random(aInitBiases[0], aInitBiases[1]);
            }
        }
    };

/****************** PUBLIC ******************/

this.id;
this.length;
this.inputs;
this.outputs;
this.gradients;
this.biases;
this.next;
this.previous;

this.inConnection;
this.outConnection;

this.isInput  = function() { return !this.previous;     }
this.isOutput = function() { return !this.next;         }

this.calculateGradients = function(aTarget) {
    var n, n1, nOutputError,
        fDerivative = Ann.Activation.Derivative[oConfig.activation];

    if (this.isOutput()) {
        for (n=0; n<oConfig.nodes; n++) {
            nOutputError = this.outputs[n] - aTarget[n];
            this.gradients[n] = nOutputError * fDerivative(this.outputs[n]);
        }
    } else {
        for (n=0; n<oConfig.nodes; n++) {
            nOutputError = 0.0;
            for (n1=0; n1<this.outConnection.weights[n].length; n1++) {
                nOutputError += this.outConnection.weights[n][n1] * this.next.gradients[n1];
            }
            // console.log(this.id, nOutputError, this.outputs[n], fDerivative(this.outputs[n]));
            this.gradients[n] = nOutputError * fDerivative(this.outputs[n]);
        }
    }
}

this.updateInputWeights = function() {
    if (!this.isInput()) {
        var nY,
            nX,
            nOldDeltaWeight,
            nNewDeltaWeight;

        for (nX=0; nX<this.previous.length; nX++) {
            for (nY=0; nY<this.length; nY++) {
                nOldDeltaWeight = this.inConnection.deltaWeights[nX][nY];
                nNewDeltaWeight =
                    - oNet.learningRate
                    * this.previous.outputs[nX]
                    * this.gradients[nY]
                    // Add momentum, a fraction of old delta weight
                    + oNet.learningMomentum
                    * nOldDeltaWeight;

                if (nNewDeltaWeight == 0 && nOldDeltaWeight != 0) {
                    console.log('Double overflow');
                }

                this.inConnection.deltaWeights[nX][nY] = nNewDeltaWeight;
                this.inConnection.weights[nX][nY]     += nNewDeltaWeight;
            }
        }
    }
}

this.updateInputBiases = function() {
    if (bUseBias && !this.isInput()) {
        var n,
            nNewDeltaBias;

        for (n=0; n<this.length; n++) {
            nNewDeltaBias = 
                - oNet.learningRate
                * this.gradients[n];

            this.biases[n] += nNewDeltaBias;
        }
    }
}

this.feedForward = function(a) {
    var fActivation = Ann.Activation[oConfig.activation];

    this.inputs = a;

    if (this.isInput()) {
        this.outputs = this.inputs;
    } else {
        for (var n=0; n<a.length; n++) {
            this.outputs[n] = fActivation(a[n] + this.biases[n]);
        }
    }
    if (!this.isOutput()) {
        this.outConnection.feedForward(this.outputs);
    }
}

_initialize();
}
```

The main feedForward and backProp functions are defined like so:

```
this.feedForward = function(a) {
    this.layers[0].feedForward(a);
    this.netError = 0;
}

this.backPropagate = function(aExample, aTarget) {
    this.target = aTarget;

    if (aExample.length != this.getInputCount())  { throw "Wrong input count in training data"; }
    if (aTarget.length  != this.getOutputCount()) { throw "Wrong output count in training data"; }

    this.feedForward(aExample);
    _calculateNetError(aTarget);

    var oLayer = null,
        nLast  = this.layers.length-1,
        n;

    for (n=nLast; n>0; n--) {
        if (n === nLast) {
            this.layers[n].calculateGradients(aTarget);
        } else {
            this.layers[n].calculateGradients();
        }
    }

    for (n=nLast; n>0; n--) {
        this.layers[n].updateInputWeights();
        this.layers[n].updateInputBiases();
    }
}
```

Connection code is rather simple:

```
Ann.Connection = function(oNet, oConfig, aInitWeights) {
var _oThis = this;

var _initialize = function() {
        var nX, nY, nIn, nOut;

        _oThis.from = oNet.layers[oConfig.from];
        _oThis.to   = oNet.layers[oConfig.to];

        nIn  = _oThis.from.length;
        nOut = _oThis.to.length;

        _oThis.weights      = new Array(nIn);
        _oThis.deltaWeights = new Array(nIn);

        for (nX=0; nX<nIn; nX++) {
            _oThis.weights[nX]      = new Array(nOut);
            _oThis.deltaWeights[nX] = new Array(nOut);
            _oThis.deltaWeights[nX].fill(0);
            for (nY=0; nY<nOut; nY++) {
                _oThis.weights[nX][nY] = Ann.random(aInitWeights[0], aInitWeights[1]);
            }
        }
    };

/****************** PUBLIC ******************/

this.weights;
this.deltaWeights;
this.from;
this.to;

this.feedForward = function(a) {
    var n, nX, nY, aOut = new Array(this.to.length);

    for (nY=0; nY<this.to.length; nY++) {
        n = 0;
        for (nX=0; nX<this.from.length; nX++) {
            n += a[nX] * this.weights[nX][nY];
        }
        aOut[nY] = n;
    }

    this.to.feedForward(aOut);
}

_initialize();
}
```

And my activation functions and derivatives are defined like so:

```
Ann.Activation = {
    linear : function(n) { return n; },
    sigma  : function(n) { return 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-n)); },
    tanh   : function(n) { return Math.tanh(n); }
}

Ann.Activation.Derivative = {
    linear : function(n) { return 1.0; },
    sigma  : function(n) { return n * (1.0 - n); },
    tanh   : function(n) { return 1.0 - n * n; }
}
```

And configuration JSON for the network is as follows:

```
var Config = {
    id : "Config1",

    learning_rate     : 0.01,
    learning_momentum : 0,
    init_weight       : [-1, 1],
    init_bias         : [-1, 1],
    use_bias          : false,

    layers: [
        {nodes : 1},
        {nodes : 4, activation : "sigma"},
        {nodes : 1, activation : "linear"}
    ],

    connections: [
        {from : 0, to : 1},
        {from : 1, to : 2}
    ]
}
```

Perhaps, your experienced eye can spot the problem with my calculations?

[SEE EXAMPLE IN JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fmess092/1/)

Comment: it works if your activation function is linear. Try initialize random weights and center and center your input. Unfortunately I cannot play with javascript

Comment: @rep_ho If you'd like a bounty, please provide an answer within a few hours. I've heard bounty disappears if no answers are posted. I would like all the little tips and tricks that you've learned about NN, similarly to what you've already covered. Thank you.

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you initialize weights with

```
init_weight       : [-1, 1],
init_bias         : [-1, 1],
```

I am not sure what does it do exactly, but i guess your weights are initialized to 1 or -1. If that is the case, then thats your first problem. Since the all weights starts at the same number, they will all produce the same error and therefore will be updated by the same amount. So you cannot really learn any pattern, because all your neurons will be doing the same.

This is not a problem with a linear activation function, because layer full of linear neurons will produce the same output as just the one linear neuron regardless. Because the linear combination of linear functions is still just a linear function.

I thought that maybe you have some bug and you are not updating all the weights but only the bias, which would explain why you will end up with the mean function. This was however not true with linear activation function, which was learning the output correctly.

Next I noticed that with sigma activation function something was happening to the outputs in the beginning of the epoch but not in the later stages and also that the network was working reasonably fine if I use only 10 inputs instead of yours default 100. That usually happen if you don't standardize the inputs before the training. If the inputs are too big, your sigmoid activation function will produce outputs close to 1, however the slope of the sigmoid at this point is close to 0, so your weights wont get updated, because the gradients are close to 0. You can fight this by standardizing the inputs, so by subtracting the mean of the vector and dividing it by its standard deviation. So your input vector will have mean 0 and std 1. This is also related problem to vanishing/exploding gradient problem, where the weights tends to grow too big/too small and you will get the same issue of the neuron outputing values close to 0/1 and therefore not updating the weights. I think you combat this by some form of regularization, for example force all weights to sum to 1 or something like that.

I tried few things in scikit learn implementation of SGD NN and indeed, neural network fail if the inputs are not standardized. However I couldn't find in your code where the heck is actual input vector, so I couldn't try if this also solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Even though I am still fighting some problems, the learning started happening a few days ago. The weight initialization that you've quoted is a range of randomization, so the weights will be assigned values from -1 to 1. So this is not the problem. Thanks for your answer, would it be possible to connect on Skype for further occasional interaction on this topic?